# PS access to directory and run commands

Tags: powershell

I am new to `PS`. Is it possible to to create a script to do the following:

1. From `Powershell`, cd to a directory
2. Run a specific command in the directory

Comment: You can _"cd to a directory"_ the same way you can do it from `cmd`, it's not clear what exactly is the problem

Comment: Hi Santiago,
The issues is the CMD unable to perform cd to a directory for a reason. 
I need the script to access to the directory and run given command (example : npm stop and start) to restart the services

Comment: _unable to perform cd to a directory for a reason_... what reason?